# How to know a row of a table has changed?

Tags: database, oracle

This is one of the requirements for new project which seems so interesting to me. I have to apply some transformations on newly changed rows of a table and leave the rest untouched.

Another restriction is that any SQL client can be used to update the db without having to accessing my application (which seems less breathless for me to implement).

Is there anyway I can know a table has changed from the last accessed in Oracle DB and which rows has changed without comparing all the values?

Comment: [Insert/update triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#BABCIBBJ) updating a version counter probably will solve it.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Thx! Nearly forgot this killer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you exactly want to do with the change data - if you want to have something very robust used for e.g. replication to another database you could use [Oracle Change Data Capture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm) but from your description it sounds as if [normal triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm) may do the trick.